# Targeting specific data items with a particular key with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON object like the following:

```
{
   "name": "cameraasd_main_autofocus",
   "value": "Lasasd autofocus",
   "displayName": "Autofocus"
 },
{
   "name": "screen_siasdze",
   "value": "5.2\asd",
   "displayName": "Sdascreen Size",
   "group": "General"
},
{
   "name": "camera_maindas_features",
   "value": "Digital Zoom,das Auto Flash, Digital image stabilization"
   "displayName": "Features"
},
```

In this data object I only want to target the element which have the `group` attribute with `ng-repeat`. And I have to further group out the elements with a particular group. For example from the whole object the elements with group value `"General"` should be separated from the rest of the elements.

Comment: check my answer for filtering with the group.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a scope variable to store the filtered items that have property "group" like below

```
var data = [{
   "name": "cameraasd_main_autofocus",
   "value": "Lasasd autofocus",
   "displayName": "Autofocus"
 },
{
   "name": "screen_siasdze",
   "value": "5.2asd",
   "displayName": "Sdascreen Size",
   "group": "General"
},
{
   "name": "camera_maindas_features",
   "value": "Digital Zoom,das Auto Flash, Digital image stabilization",
   "displayName": "Features"
}];

$scope.filteredData = data.filter(function(x){ return x.hasOwnProperty("group")});
```

and then use `ng-repeat` in UI

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in filteredData">
      {{item.name}} || {{item.value}} 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a working sample : https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/8267/

**Edit :** if you want to separate out the elements based on a particular group name then you can try the below code

```
$scope.filteredData = data.filter(function(x){ return x.hasOwnProperty("group") && x.group == "General"});
```

in this case only `General` groups will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records">
    <div ng-if="x.group"> {{x.name}} </div>
</div>
```

try out if this works!! Good Luck!

Comment: This worked. Can you help me to seperate out the elements with a particular group

Comment: @ujjwalgupta i have updated my answer to show only the general groups.

Comment: sure @ujjwalgupta.. you could use this  $scope.groupX = yourJSONData.filter(groupWithANameX => groupWithANameX .group === "Features") . and then in the above html you could replace records with groupX .

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your JSON contains an array (which is not show in your json but i assume it's there).
First, parse your JSON to a JsonObject, then get it as an array

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
```

Then you can do this in your html

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in jsonArray">
   <a ng-if="elem.group">{{ elem.property }}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code.

```
<div>
        <h3>With Group</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="d in data">
            <div ng-if="d.group">
                {{d.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Without Group</h3>
        <div ng-repeat="d in data">
            <div ng-if="!d.group">
                {{d.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```